# Direct editing with kate

Tags: kate

When I open the **kate** editor on a file, the window displays a search/replace section that takes up most of the screen. How can I make that go away and edit the file directly?  I can do that in the top of the screen, but I really want the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the sidebar and the search and replace bar which is at the bottom of the screen.

First, click on "View" in your top menu.

Then, click on "Tool Views".

Finally, untick the box for "Show Search and Replace".

Now, if you want to completely hide the search and replace box and the sidebar, you can press: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.